# Having trouble finding the correct substitution for this integral.

Tags: calculus

the problem: $\int 3^{x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x$

I have tried doing some subitution but I can't seem to get a du that works.

$\sqrt{u} = 3^x$ which didn't work,

$u = 3^{x^2}$ -I couldn't find a du for this that I trust.

$\ln u= x^2 \ln 3$ and  and several others.

I haven't found any way to rearrage the variables to get a nice du so I can solve it. Meaning I haven't found a way to account for all the $x$ inorder to do subutition.

Am I on the correct path, is subution the method to solve this?

The answer sheets says $$\frac{3^{x^2}}{\ln 9} + C$$

Comment: Is it $3^{x^2}$ or $3^x$?

Comment: I don't think $3^{x^2}$ has an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: What he is asking is a non elementary integral!

Comment: See [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+3%5Ex%5E2)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+3%5E%7Bx%5E2%7D+dx+
But as it gives no steps its quite useless

Comment: I think the problem is wrong or the answer sheet is wrong.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I have edit the question.

Comment: The derivative of $\dfrac{3^{x^2}}{\ln9}$ is $x3^{x^2}$. Maybe there is a typo in the problem.

Comment: I believe the function is $3^{2x}$.

Comment: Everybody cool down.  What he's asking is to find the integral of $(3^x)^2 = 3^{2x} = 9^x$, which happily does have an antiderivative in elementary functions.

Comment: @andybenji: This is what I already put in the comment.

Comment: @OP Why don't you modify the text and the title of the question so that what is written is what you mean to ask and not something completely different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the question is asking is for the antiderivative of $(3^x)^2 = 3^{2x} = 9^x$.  Since $9 = e^{\ln(9)}$, we may substitute this in, so we have that $$ \int 9^x dx = \int e^{\ln(9)x} dx = \frac{e^{\ln(9)x}}{\ln(9)} + C = \frac{9^x}{\ln(9)} + C$$

Answer (score 2):

See [Error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). Your problem reduces to this by trivial rescaling: $3^{x^2} = e^{-(i(\ln 3)^{1/2} x)^2}$.

Comment: The identity is wrong and I fail to see how it would help.

Comment: @did: Corrected, thanks. If the OP really meant not $3^{2x}$ but $3^{x^2}$, as she stated very explicitly by writing the braces, the answer would be $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2 i \sqrt{\ln 3}} \mathrm{erf[i \sqrt{\ln 3} \cdot x]}$.

Answer (score 2):

If$\; C=(3^x)^2=3^{2x}$.
We could take logarithm both sides.

Hence,
$$
\ln C=\ln 3^{2x}=2x\ln 3\\
\begin{align}
C=e^{2x\ln 3}\\
\therefore\; 3^{2x}=e^{2x\ln 3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,using substitution  $ u=2x\ln3 $
$$
\int 3^{2x}dx\;
\begin{align}
=\int e^{2x\ln3}dx
=\frac{1}{2\ln3}\int e^udu
=\frac{e^{2x\ln3}}{2\ln3}+C
=\frac{(3^x)^2}{2\ln3}+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the following

$$ \int 3^{2x}dx = \int 9^x dx = \int e^{\ln(9) x} dx = \frac{e^{\ln(9) x}}{\ln(9)}=\frac{{3^{2x}}}{\ln(9)}. $$